How do I fix the edging/border between tile and vinyl flooring - it was ripped in half?
This piece of edging (?) the connects the tile floor to the vinyl floor by my fireplace started to come up at one corner and my toddler ended up ripping it in half. What's the best way to replace/fix? I tried gluing the piece back down as a temp fix and that didn't last very long.


Welcome to DIY.SE! The picture would do better to be posted here rather than in the link which could go dead. Please use the Edit Link, then the Mountain icon, to post the picture to DIY.


What's the best way to replace/fix?

The best way is to replace it. Fixing it is not possible, such that it goes back to what it was before it was stress-tested by your budding mechanical engineer.
Take the pieces to a flooring store. They may be able to get you an exact replacement strip. The flooring store may be able to show you how to connect the replacement strips back to the floor. There may be a press-fit channel screwed to the floor that the new strips can fit into, or you may have to replace the press-fit channel as well.
If you cannot find an exact replacement strip, then you might have to take all of the trim pieces off and replace them with new pieces completely, so the new trim all looks the same.
Then you'll have to take the replacement strip to a cabinet shop or a friend who has a miter box or miter saw to cut the angled end and cut to correct length.
If the press-fit channel is compatible with the new piece, press the piece back in and you're done. If the replacement trim needed new press-fit channel, you'd have to remove the old channel as well, install the new channel, then press in the new trim strips.
